# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::sqlsrv_prepare()

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, prepared-statement

I know my question is a duplicate but I can't find the solution today. I got a tqo files db connection:

```
<?php
$serverName ="host\SQLEXPRESS";
 $usr="sa";
 $pwd="SysAdmin";
 $db="db_name";

//$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

//$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=host\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db_name", "sa", "SysAdmin");
?>
```

My action file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'db1.php';

$name='11111';
$sql_user = $conn -> sqlsrv_prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id= :name");

$sql_user -> sqlsrv_execute(array(':name' => $name));
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_user))
  {
echo $row['name'];

}
?>
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::sqlsrv_prepare() on line 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlsrv_*` doesn't exist in PDO.

The PDO-API is in all database drivers the same. Thats the idea behind PDO.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'db1.php';

$name='11111';
$sql_user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id= :name");
$sql_user->execute(array(':name' => $name));

$row = $sql_user->fetchAll();
var_dump($row);
```

---

**update:**
to get only the name row:

```
$row = $sql_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row['name']);
```

[PHP Manual PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
>   in your result set

Comment: Its work but how to get 1 record from db where column name = $name?

Comment: example: echo $row['name'];

Comment: So if i will change all my code to like this thats mean my system will be protected from sql injections?

Comment: with `prepare`and `execute` yes

Comment: Could you give example of a SQL injection? What i need to insert in to my field to test?